# SAS multiplying columns in one table with matching names with columns in another table

Tags: sas

I am working in SAS.

I have two tables each with the same column names.
Var1-Var189
but it skips numbers.
I basically need to multiply each matching column name by its partner. Due to the size of table 1 doing this through transpose takes 4+ hours. Need to find a way to do it quicker.

Table 1

```
|Var1| Var2 | Var6 | Var9 |
|:---|:-----|:-----|:-----|
|1.2 |1.4   | 1.3  | 0.68 |
|1.4 |1.8   |1.6   | 0.85 |
```

Table 2

```
|Var1| Var2 | Var6 | Var9 |
|:---|:-----|:-----|:-----|
|1   |0     | 0    | 1    |
```

Table 3 (want):
Table 1

```
|Var1| Var2 | Var6 | Var9 |
|:---|:-----|:-----|:-----|
|1.2 |0     | 0    | 0.68 |
|1.4 |0     |0     | 0.85 |
```

Table 2 will always have 1 or 0, but they shift. It will also only have 1 row.

Comment: How are the rows match?  Can you show(as text) an example of each table?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your existing code - preferably in a way we can run it (with a data step creating a dummy dataset).

Comment: Table 1
Var1   var2    var6   var9

Comment: I added table examples in

Comment: @VanessaApodaca Not exactly what I expected to see.  Can you now show output you want based on the example Table 1 and 2?  Are values in Table 2 always 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

Base on the data you provided you could used PROC SCORE.

```
data t1;
   input Var1 Var2 Var6 Var9;
   cards;
1.2 1.4 1.3 0.68 
1.4 1.8 1.6 0.85
;;;;

data t2;
   input _type_ $ _name_ $ Var1 Var2 Var6 Var9;   
   cards;
SCORE SVAR1  1 . . .
SCORE SVAR2  . 0 . .  
SCORE SVAR6  . . 0 .  
SCORE SVAR9  . . . 1  
;;;;
   
proc score data=t1 score=t2 out=t3;
   var var:;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

IF you want to keep the original variable names VARn that can be accomplished with a dummy ID variable as follows.

```
data t1;
   retain dummy 1;
   input Var1 Var2 Var6 Var9;
   cards;
1.2 1.4 1.3 0.68 
1.4 1.8 1.6 0.85
;;;;

data t2;
   input Var1 Var2 Var6 Var9;
   cards;
1 0 0 1
;;;;
proc transpose data=t2 out=t2s;
   var var:;
   run;
data t2s;
   retain _TYPE_ 'SCORE';
   set t2s;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=t2s out=tscore name=x;
   by _type_ _name_;
   id _name_;
   var col1;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc score data=t1 score=tscore out=t3;
   id dummy;
   var var:;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]